# Python csv, if check using header

Tags: python, csv, header

I have a file daiy.csv which is updated on daily basis. The script fetches values out of it, checks against some values and then prints out some info based on those checks. My problem is that almost once a week, the column numbers in daily.csv either increase or decrease. Then I have to find the new column number for my desired values. I was wondering if there is a way I can use header values in my if checks so regardless the column numbers change, I can still run my script.

```
with open('daily.csv','rb')as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        #next(reader, None) #Skipping the header
        for row in reader:
                #if row[3]=='M2' and (float(row[38]) > 60):
                try:
                        if (row[3]=='M2' or row[3]=='M4' or row[3]=='M3') and (float(row[37]) > 60):
                                print row[1] + "/" + row[2] + "/" + row[3] + " : " +  row[37]
                        if (row[3]=='M2' or row[3]=='M4' or row[3]=='M3') and (float(row[37]) < 70):
                                print row[1] + "/" + row[2] + "/" + row[3] + " : " + row[37]
                except:
                        pass
```

Comment: Well, probably can adjust for number of columns dynamically, but what is **your** logic for those tests and how would they change if a column gets added or deleted?

Comment: The logic is in try block that I want to match specific values. If the columns are added or deleted, row[3] column can become row[4]. If I can use column header instead of row[3] then it doesn't matter how many columns are added or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem that pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) can easily help you solve. Assuming that all of your columns have unique headers you can just extract the relevant columns you care about. Let's say that your column names are 'A', 'B', and 'C' and you don't want to analyze column 'B'.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('daily.csv')    
columns_to_analyze = ['A', 'C']
df = df[columns_to_analyze]
```

Without knowing more specifics of how 'daily.csv' is formatted that's as much as I can confidently say...